# Laravel select not working properly inside the "WITH"

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I have following controller in my laravel application, to fetch and send data to my vue component.

I recently added new column called `added_by` which stores the user id of the user who add the record. It's a foreign key value and referred to the users able. Now I'm trying to display that user's first name on my vue component.

I able to do that with following for loop

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Corporate\Employee;

use App\Company;
use App\Models\OtherDocument;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CompanyEmployeeOtherDocumentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param string $locale
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(string $locale, Company $company, User $user)
    {

        $otherDocuments = OtherDocument::where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->with('added_by_user')
            ->when(request('validity_status'), function ($query) {
                $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->when( in_array('active', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->where(function (Builder $query) {
                            $query->whereDate('issued_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
                                ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->addMonth());
                        })->orWhere('is_valid_forever',1);
                    })->when( in_array('expires', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->orWhere(function (Builder $query) {
                            $query->whereDate('expires_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->addMonth())
                                ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now());
                        });
                    })->when( in_array('expired', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->orWhereDate('expires_at', '<', Carbon::now());
                    });
                });
            })
            ->when(request('search_text'), function ($query) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . request('search_text') . '%');
            })
            ->paginate(request('per_page',config('statguru.pagination.limit')));

        for ($i=0; $i < count($otherDocuments); $i++) {
            $addedByUser = $otherDocuments[$i]->added_by_user;
            if ($addedByUser) {
                $otherDocuments[$i]['added_user_name'] = $addedByUser->first_name . ' ' . $addedByUser->last_name;
            }
        }

        return  response()->json($otherDocuments);

    }
}
```

But now I need to remove the for loop and instead of that use a function.

This is what I tried so far,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Corporate\Employee;

use App\Company;
use App\Models\OtherDocument;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CompanyEmployeeOtherDocumentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param string $locale
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(string $locale, Company $company, User $user)
    {

        $otherDocuments = OtherDocument::where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->when(request('validity_status'), function ($query) {
                $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->when( in_array('active', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->where(function (Builder $query) {
                            $query->whereDate('issued_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
                                ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->addMonth());
                        })->orWhere('is_valid_forever',1);
                    })->when( in_array('expires', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->orWhere(function (Builder $query) {
                            $query->whereDate('expires_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->addMonth())
                                ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now());
                        });
                    })->when( in_array('expired', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->orWhereDate('expires_at', '<', Carbon::now());
                    });
                });
            })
            ->when(request('search_text'), function ($query) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . request('search_text') . '%');
            })
            ->with(['added_by_user' => function($query) {
                $query->select('first_name');
            }])
            ->paginate(request('per_page',config('statguru.pagination.limit')));

        return  response()->json($otherDocuments);

    }
}
```

but this is not giving me the correct out put as it used to be with for loop.

I'm using the laravel 9.

I display that value on my vuejs datatable as

```
{text: 'Added By', value: 'added_user_name'},
```

inside the header array

Answer (score 0):

Do a one to many relationship on the models on the user. Then use With() in your eloquent to call that relationship. Then you will have all the user info associated with that document.